# webpack dev server not serving (but compiles)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to setup a basic webpack config for react and serve it in dev mode using webpack dev server. Webpack compiles everything just fine, but the files aren't served when using webpack dev server... I am hosting the project on a VPS and tested whether the server is reachable using a boilerplate create-react-app dev server - it is. I can see the project just fine going to 'http://serverIPv4:3000'. Webpack dev server project is configured to serve on port 9000 - and that does not work, even though the files are being compiled. It also doesn't work on default port 8080 or 3000. What am I missing?

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.jsx'
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },

};

module.exports = config;
```

**devDependencies**:

```
"webpack": "^5.11.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
```

**project structure**:

```
dist
 |-index.html
src
 |-App.js
 |-index.js
 |-styles.css
```

**Console output**:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/ubuntu/rcw-webpack/dist
ℹ ｢wdm｣: asset bundle.js 1.36 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 1.25 KiB 6 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.29 MiB 32 modules
modules by path ./src/ 4.32 KiB
  modules by path ./src/*.js 3.65 KiB
    ./src/index.js 244 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.js 3.41 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/*.css 681 bytes
    ./src/styles.css 327 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles.css 354 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.11.1 compiled successfully in 2535 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

**UPDATE: package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "rcw-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --env development",
    "build-prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.14",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json code, the issue might be with script config.

Comment: @HemantMalik: updated the post with package.json. I know "--env development" mode in start script is an overkill, but I used it following this comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759#issuecomment-707458759

Comment: tested shared webpack config on a dummy react project, it worked properly. i don't see any issue in package.json also. What is it showing on http://localhost:9000/ on npm start?

Comment: I always get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error, tried on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge. I do have ufw installed on the VPS machine, but I turned it off completely. Also I know the port is reachable when trying dev server on create-react-app...

Comment: I think the problem is with your server configuration, as ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED also doesn't sound like a react error, and also in your shared console output clearly shows  ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/.

Comment: have a look at this https://kinsta.com/blog/err_connection_refused/

Comment: Well, thanks for looking into this anyways. Something is clearly wrong, but for now I found a (clumsy, yet working) way around this and I'm serving static bundle via nginx ;) not ideal, but I actually already have some components built using create-react-app, just need to transfer them over to this 'clean' webpack project. So not expecting heavy development, maybe some bug fixes, which the nginx setup satisfies for now.

Comment: @mintymike have you solved the issue?